# Compiling gcc fails while trying to link libgcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, musl

I am trying to build gcc for my linux. I'm cross compiling since I don't have a preexisting gcc.

I'm using musl as libc.

I configured gcc like this:

```
export CFLAGS="-pipe -march=native -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -pie -fpie"
../gcc-10.1.0/configure --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl \
                        --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu \
                        --enable-lto --prefix=/usr --disable-nls --disable-multilib \
                        --enable-languages=c --without-isl --with-newlib --disable-libsanitizer \
                        --with-sysroot=/root/mnt
```

When I run `make` gcc compiles for a few minutes. After a while the build tries to execute the following

```
x86_64-unknown-linux-musl-gcc   -O2  -g -O2 -pipe -march=native -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -pie -fpie -DIN_GCC    -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include   -fpic -mlong-double-80 -DUSE_ELF_SYMVER  -DGTHREAD_USE_WEAK=0 -g -DIN_LIBGCC2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector -Dinhibit_libc -shared -nodefaultlibs -Wl,--soname=libgcc_s.so.1 -Wl,--version-script=libgcc.map -o ./libgcc_s.so.1.tmp -g -O2 -pipe -march=native -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -pie -fpie -B./ _muldi3_s.o _negdi2_s.o _lshrdi3_s.o _ashldi3_s.o _ashrdi3_s.o _cmpdi2_s.o _ucmpdi2_s.o _clear_cache_s.o _trampoline_s.o __main_s.o _absvsi2_s.o _absvdi2_s.o _addvsi3_s.o _addvdi3_s.o _subvsi3_s.o _subvdi3_s.o _mulvsi3_s.o _mulvdi3_s.o _negvsi2_s.o _negvdi2_s.o _ctors_s.o _ffssi2_s.o _ffsdi2_s.o _clz_s.o _clzsi2_s.o _clzdi2_s.o _ctzsi2_s.o _ctzdi2_s.o _popcount_tab_s.o _popcountsi2_s.o _popcountdi2_s.o _paritysi2_s.o _paritydi2_s.o _powisf2_s.o _powidf2_s.o _powixf2_s.o _mulhc3_s.o _mulsc3_s.o _muldc3_s.o _mulxc3_s.o _divhc3_s.o _divsc3_s.o _divdc3_s.o _divxc3_s.o _bswapsi2_s.o _bswapdi2_s.o _clrsbsi2_s.o _clrsbdi2_s.o _fixunssfsi_s.o _fixunsdfsi_s.o _fixunsxfsi_s.o _fixsfdi_s.o _fixdfdi_s.o _fixxfdi_s.o _fixunssfdi_s.o _fixunsdfdi_s.o _fixunsxfdi_s.o _floatdisf_s.o _floatdidf_s.o _floatdixf_s.o _floatundisf_s.o _floatundidf_s.o _floatundixf_s.o _divdi3_s.o _moddi3_s.o _divmoddi4_s.o _udivdi3_s.o _umoddi3_s.o _udivmoddi4_s.o _udiv_w_sdiv_s.o sfp-exceptions_s.o addtf3_s.o divtf3_s.o multf3_s.o negtf2_s.o subtf3_s.o unordtf2_s.o fixtfsi_s.o fixunstfsi_s.o floatsitf_s.o floatunsitf_s.o fixtfdi_s.o fixunstfdi_s.o floatditf_s.o floatunditf_s.o fixtfti_s.o fixunstfti_s.o floattitf_s.o floatuntitf_s.o extendsftf2_s.o extenddftf2_s.o extendxftf2_s.o trunctfsf2_s.o trunctfdf2_s.o trunctfxf2_s.o getf2_s.o letf2_s.o eqtf2_s.o _divtc3_s.o _multc3_s.o _powitf2_s.o enable-execute-stack_s.o unwind-dw2_s.o unwind-dw2-fde-dip_s.o unwind-sjlj_s.o unwind-c_s.o emutls_s.o libgcc.a -lc
```

in my build directory under `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/libgcc` which fails with:

```
/root/mnt/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/bin/ld: /root/mnt/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/Scrt1.o: in function `_start_c':
Scrt1.c:(.text._start_c+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I verified with `objdump -t crt1.o` and `objdump -t Scrt1.o` that these object files define `main`, which they do.

Im pretty confused by now because the name `libgcc` suggests that it's a library, which of course does not have a `main` method. Why is `ld` expecting one? What is the build trying to do here?

Comment: Try turning off LTO as I am not sure that LD supports this.  You would need gold or LLD I think.  Might be a bitcode vs obj file issue.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I added the CFLAGS to the question. I am not using LTO for building. I just wanted to build a gcc that would support lto. But itself should not be linked using lto.